# Implementing COG's plugin with Docker's image with Google Cloud Storage on VM

Tags: geoserver, cloud-optimized-geotiff, google-cloud

I'm running geoserver on a Virtual Machine on Cloud engine through Docker, this is the dockerfile I'm using to build the image as [this documentation says](https://docs.geoserver.org/main/en/user/installation/docker.html):

```
    # Use the GeoServer image as the base
    FROM docker.osgeo.org/geoserver:2.25.x
    
    # Set the environment variables
    ENV INSTALL_EXTENSIONS=true \
        STABLE_EXTENSIONS="ysld,h2" \
        COMMUNITY_EXTENSIONS="cog"
    
    
    COPY ./auth/credentials.json /auth/
    
    ENV GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/auth/credentials.json
    # Expose port 8080 for the GeoServer
    EXPOSE 8080
```

But then, when I try to create the store on geoserver i face this error: [image: COG server]

I'm following [these steps](https://docs.geoserver.org/main/en/user/community/cog/cog.html) but it doesn't seems to work at all.

The console description isn't precise about it at all. Has someone successfully created an stored instance of an image or faced something similar?

Comment: looks like GeoServer can't access the cog

Comment: I tried it hosting the COG on other buckets and still fails at fetching it

Comment: Maybe it can't see out of the container?